# display if checkbox is checked while editing

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

As i had gone through several solutions i didnt get an solution for this. when i go for editing and open the page i want to show the list of check boxes as marked that i chooses while inserting.
Here is my view page..

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="courses">Courses Completed</label>
         <div class=" col-sm-5">

         <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" value="10" <?php if($row->courses =='10') echo "checked" ;?>>10
         <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" value="12" <?php if($row->courses =='12') echo "checked" ;?>>12
         <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" value="degree" <?php if($row->courses=='degree') echo "checked" ;?>>degree

         </div>
    </div>
```

by doing like this none of the checkbox is showing as checked state.the value inserted is like an array and my table looks like this

```
id  name        address             sex     courses     places                 image            password
 1  nesru         v                 male    "10"        tamilnadu   upld-file1469095130.jpg       l
 3  siraj   koonathil house        male     "10,12"     tamilnadu   upld-file1469167954.jpg       d
```

Comment: can you print $row->courses

Comment: show the output of `print_r($row->courses);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per table you have posted it seems you are storing comma separated value in courses, for that you need to convert in array and check using `in_array()` function

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-1" for="courses">Courses Completed</label>
   <?php $idArray = explode(",",$row->courses); ?>
    <div class=" col-sm-5">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" rel="<?php echo $row->courses; ?>" value="10" <?php if(in_array('10',$idArray)) echo "checked" ;?>>10
        <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" rel="<?php echo $row->courses; ?>" value="12" <?php if(in_array('12',$idArray)) echo "checked" ;?>>12
        <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" rel="<?php echo $row->courses; ?>" value="degree" <?php if(in_array('degree',$idArray)) echo "checked" ;?>>degree
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i had used json_encode  to insert values so need to decode it?

Comment: i had decoded it got it...thanks alot..changed like this <?php $idArray = explode(",",json_decode($row->courses)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

The attribute for checked state is checked=""

Put your php code in the quotes

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" value="degree" checked="<?php if($row->courses=='degree') echo "checked" ;?>" />
```

Comment: i had given like this but all the checkbox are showing as marked

Comment: @MOHAMMED  you have to show the output of `print_r($row->courses);` to us other wise every one just guess. putt hat output in your code

Comment: Then I will have to agree with the above commenters you need the contents of print_r ($row->courses);  it sounds like the error is in the retrieval of the data from a database or wherever you are drawing from

Comment: my print_r($row->courses); looks like this  "10,12"

Answer (score 0):

You should put following code :

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="select_course[]" id="select_course" value="degree" <?php if($row->courses=='degree'): ?> checked="checked" <?php endif; ?> />
```